# Custom ultimo theme + magento 1.9.2.2

Tags: css, themes

I'm using the Ultimo theme by infortins.

My block_header_top_left and also the right (phone, email and welcome message), are not display below 768, in responsive view, whatever my settings from CMS block admin. Can anyone tell me what file and line from CSS should i modify ?

i installed the theme as default, without any changes, on Magento 1.9.2.2 version.

Comment: There is not enough insights in your question for the community to answer. Have you tried to modify the theme yet?

Comment: thank you, not from css.